# Zero tangent of a 3D Bezier curve, how to handle?

Tags: math, exception, bezier

As peculiar as it seems, the direction (tangent) of a Bezier curve may be zero (0,0,0) at some point. E.g. for the symmetrical Bezier curve defined as:

```
    bezier.anchor1.copyFrom(new Vector3D(-1,0,0));
    bezier.control1.copyFrom(new Vector3D(1,0,0));
    bezier.anchor2.copyFrom(new Vector3D(1,0,0));
    bezier.control2.copyFrom(new Vector3D(-1.,0,0));
```

the direction at t=0.5 is (0,0,0). This might be a rare/extreme use case, but I definitely need to always have a non-zero direction at hand.

Programmatically speaking, how should I handle it? Recalculate the direction at another nearby t (say t1=t*0.99999=0.499995) and return that direction instead?

Comment: If it is a rare case (like an exception) then why not handle the calculated result? `if tangent == [0, 0, 0] then ...`

Comment: What language is this?  Why is a zero direction an issue?

Comment: @karatedog That's what I asked. If tangent == (0,0,0) recalc at t=0.999*t. I am asking if this is a good idea or if there are far better ones

Comment: @Degustaf The language is irrelevant, but FYI it's Flash AS3. A zero direction is an issue because if I set a zero direction to my 3D model (which is supposed to follow the 3D curve), I get an exception in my face.

Comment: The curve is probably a degenerate case. You are drawing the segment `[(-1,0,0),(1,0,0)]`, no ?

Comment: @BillKotsias Beziér curves are parametric curves, and those are not mathematical functions. So I would handle this case as I suggested above, the same way I would handle the derivative of abs(0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things are a little worse than your example. Its quite possible to have a [cusp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)) occurring in a cubic Bezier curve. For example with control points [80,214], [217,50], [75,50], [222,206]. Your example is actually a flattened cusp.

[image: Picture of a cusp].

Cusps are quite tricky to deal with if you follow the tangents to the curve they go through a 180º flip at the cusp point. Cusps are also quite common, if you have an animated sequence of curves you are likely to have a cusp occurring in one frame as a loop unfolds. You see them quite often in the real world, in the pattern of light at the bottom of a teacup, and in the projection of curves in 3D onto 2D (eg project the curve (t,t^2,t^3) onto the Y-Z plane). The good news is that they are generally isolated points, you'll only ever get one on a cubic Bezier curve.

Now how to handle these cusps might depend on you application. If it say describes the path of some object what will happen is the object comes to a standstill at the cusp point and leaves in the opposite direction. It might be quite reasonable to say the object has a zero tangent vector at this point. It might be possible to split the curve at the cusp point.

You can see an interactive example with movable control points  http://jsfiddle.net/SalixAlba/QQnvm/6/ In javascript with a canvas

```
var P = [{X:  80, Y: 214 }, 
         {X: 217, Y:  50 }, 
         {X:  75, Y:  50 }, 
         {X: 222, Y: 206 }, ];
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(P[0].X, P[0].Y);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(P[1].X, P[1].Y, P[2].X, P[2].Y, P[3].X, P[3].Y);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't know why you can't have a `0` norm vector as a derivative. I suppose you're trying to animate something along a curve, then that derivative is the speed... and your speed at that point is zero because you're momentarily not moving. There should be no problem with that.

### Why `0` ? Let's look at a pathological case

See this illustration where the anchors are `(-1,-y,0)` and `(-1,y,0)` and control points `(1,-y,0)`, `(1,y,0)`respectively.

[image]

Now you see what happens to the tangent that is drawn at parameter-defined points `t=0`, `t=0.5`, and `t=1`. At `t=0.5`, the tangent has lost all its component among the `x` axis but is still shifting slowly towards thee `y` axis, thus having a small tangent to the right.

However the more you modify this `y` parameter to become `0`, you will flatten the curve and obtain a segment. At the points `t=0.5`, your tangent not have a zero `x` compoenent (like before) but also on the `y` dimension since the figure will be one-dimensional.

So a zero tangent is a pathological case that may arise when your figure has too little dimensions.

### Work-around : reducing the degree

There are many orders for a Beziers curve, the formula for a generic order `n` is :

[image]

with **P**<sub>*i*</sub> the points of your curve, and the b<sub>i</sub> are known as [Bernstein basis polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial) of degree n (see [this wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Constructing_B.C3.A9zier_curves) for different illustrations of different orders of the curve).

In your case, you are going from `(-1,0,0)` to `(1,0,0)`, with control points on that same line, effectively drawing the segment `[(-1,0,0), (1,0,0)]`. Thus you draw a segment, and you only really need 2 points : you should use a first order polynomial, which is defined by `t * P0 + (1-t) * P1`, a trivial interpolation. In your formalism that would be, I guess :

```
bezier.anchor1.copyFrom(new Vector3D(-1,0,0));
bezier.anchor2.copyFrom(new Vector3D(1,0,0));
```

and no control points.
Then no `0` tangents (unless you get a cusp) !